# Изменение внешнего вида выбранного TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

Здравствуйте, имею в своём приложении собственный обозреватель папок. В целом он функционирует хорошо, но есть один недочёт: если нажать на тот, или иной `TreeViewItem`, то он обводиться стандартным и не красивым синим прямоугольником. Как это можно изменить? Надо заменить этот прямоугольник чем-то...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Элементы `TreeView` неявно (или явно, если ваш код это указывает) кладутся в `TreeViewItem`. Визуализация выбранных элементов/элементов с фокусом делается в `TreeViewItem`'е. То есть, вам нужно переопределить, как он выглядит.

Насколько я понимаю, для этого вам нужно поменять его стиль (`ItemContainerStyle`), причём целиком. Кажется, нет возможности подменять лишь часть стиля. [Вот здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728671%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) дан код, как этот стиль определён по умолчанию. (Ищите `Style TargetType="controls:TreeViewItem"`.) Определение реально большое, но правильное.

Его можно переопределить например так, как описано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5047576/276994) (хотя техника немного устарела: вместо триггеров нужно бы использовать `VisualState`). Или вы можете базироваться на стиле по умолчанию, и подменить нужные части.

Answer (score 1):

Вам следует переопределить системный цвет, который хранится в ресурсе `SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey` на который и ссылается стандартный стиль `TreeViewItem`. Пример:

```
<TreeView>
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
         </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeViewItem Header="test">
            <TreeViewItem Header="test"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="test"></TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
```